# Laravel - escape all HTML characters apart from <img> and <br> tags

Tags: php, laravel, security, xss

I am creating a forum to which I only want img tags to be displayed and all other tags to be securely escaped, ***but not*** deleted. What is the best method to accomplish this task other than creating a function from scratch?

I have tried using HTML Purifier, but it strips all the unwanted tags and only keeps the desired ones. Furthermore, I tried other functions such as strip_tags and `htmlentities` and also the escape operator used in blaede (`{{ }}`) but these functions will either strip the unwanted tags (which I want them to be escaped instead) or escape all the tags (which I also don't want to because I want to keep the `<img>` and `<br>` tags. I seen other similar asked questions, but none of them really helped me unfortunately.

So far what I do is using:
`$post->content = Purifier::clean($request->content);`
To remove the unwanted tags temporary to prevent XSS.

I expect after the data the user has inserted to be displayed like the following:

```
Hi all
<script>alert('hi all')</script>
<img src='sun.png'/>
```

While now the following is being displayed

```
Hi all
 hi all 
<img src='sun.png'/>
```

***UPDATE:***

My question is ***not*** duplicated to the question which was marked. Hopefully a moderator will resolve this.

Comment: @zbee He said he doesn't want to strip them.

Comment: @zbee I clearly mentioned that I ***dont**** want to strip the tags. _all other tags to be securely escaped, but not deleted_

Comment: @Samad _all other tags to be securely escaped, but not deleted_

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `<img>` and `<br>` tags with some string placeholders first, do the escaping with `htmlentities()` and then restore original `<img>` and `<br>` tags back. Here's how you can do the trick:

```
$string = "Hi<br> all<script>alert('hi all')</script><img src='sun.png'/>";

// First we cleanup our string from possible pre-existing placeholders (like $$0, $$1 etc).
$string = preg_replace('~\$\$[0-9]+~', '', $string);

// Then we replace all <img> and <br> tags with such placeholders while
// storing them into $placeholders array.
$placeholders = [];
$i = 0;
$string = preg_replace_callback('~(<img[^>]*>(</img>)?|<br[^>]*>)~', function ($matches) use (&$placeholders, &$i) {
    $key = '$$'.$i++;
    $placeholders[$key] = $matches[0];

    return $key;
}, $string);

// Our string no longer has <img> and <br> tags so we can safely escape
// the rest.
$string = htmlentities($string);

// Lastly we restore <img> and <br> tags by swapping them back instead of their respective placeholders.
foreach ($placeholders as $key => $placeholder) {
    $string = str_replace($key, $placeholder, $string);
}

echo $string;
```

This code will produce the result:

```
Hi<br> all&lt;script&gt;alert('hi all')&lt;/script&gt;<img src='sun.png'/>
```

This solution heavily relies on using regular expressions, so I highly advise you learning on this topic in case later on you will have a need to tweak the code.

Comment: Hi @d3jn, thanks for your answer. It works on my end and I understood your code. However, I am assuming there is no a better way, correct? In my case, I changed the key slightly in order to allow users to type stuff like $$1 which is rare.

Comment: @GeorGios sadly, I am not aware of any out of the box solution in PHP for your problem. Wrap this code into a custom global function that receives parameters similarly to how `strip_tags` does it except name it `escape_tags` or something (you can also add code that will generate regular expression out of array of incoming tags and so on) and use it throughout your project.